# Bounded derivatives over compact set, lipschitz mapping

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let us fix $n,m\in \mathbb{N}^*$. And we consider the mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C^1$.

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$ be a compact set.

We deduce that $\|\nabla_x g\|$ and  $\|\nabla_y g\|$ are bounded over $K$.

My question is that can we deduce the existence of $L\geq 0$ such that
$$\|g(x,y)- g(a,b)\|\leq L(\|x-a\|   +\|y-b \|),$$
for all $(x,y),(a,b)\in K$.

Or do we need anoher hypothesis on $K$ to obtain that $g$ is Lipschitz over $K$.

Comment: These assumptions are enough. Just apply some mean value theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables

Comment: @daw thanks for the reference, but I think we need the convexity (it is also mentioned in the reference that you gave)

Comment: Just take the convex hull of $K$, which is compact as well.